# UE4 - openGL context

Tags: opengl, c++, unreal-4

Is there a way to get an openGL context to do my drawings in UE4?

I'd like to use some shaders before the loading of a scene (kind of an intro thingy), but I couldn't find anything related to get an openGL context.

Comment: UE can use DirectX or OpenGL. The thing you want to do might be not portable.

Comment: Simply use some shader and texture logic or most conveniently just use a pre rendered video

Comment: Try to do the drawing using the tools UE4 already provides... I think it might be bad to attempt to modify the context the engine creates outside the environment it has for you.

Comment: hello, have you solved this? could you provide some updated information about how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

It's not an appropriate answer, but you can do this...
You may go deep inside UE4 source code, rewrite the things you need; since it has free access it's possible. But it will hurt, promise you.